# Use CancelAsync() to stop a specific webclient download in progress

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio, asynchronous, webclient

I'm working on a project that essentially has a few dozen checkboxes, which asynchronously downloads the files that correspond to the selected checkboxes after a button press.

The download functionality is working properly, yet some of the files are larger in size and I wanted to be able to cancel each individual download as needed.  I'm monitoring the download progress via a datalistview, and have a "cancel" DataGridViewButtonColumn for each download.  Unfortunately, CancelAsync() doesn't seem to accept paramaters - I was hoping to be able to do something like: CancelAsync(url).  I'm using a single webclient, which doesn't seem to have any adverse affects with the actual downloads, but would I need to declare a separate webclient for each individual download in order to be able to cancel them individually? (and in turn have completed/changed AddHandlers for each?)

I'm hoping for a simpler solution, but if there isn't one I'm willing to do that.  Alternately, is there a way to cancel all current downloads in progress?

[edit]
Here's my current code for the cancel buttons in the datagridview:

```
Private Sub CellContentClick(ByVal sender As DataGridView, _
                     ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
                     Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    'make sure click not on header and column is of type ButtonColumn
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso sender.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).GetType() = _
                               GetType(DataGridViewButtonColumn) Then
        'TODO - Execute Code Here
        cli.CancelAsync()
        cli.Dispose()
    End If
End Sub
```

As it stands this will cancel only the last download - I located the issue with this though, I had the webclient declared at the class level - so it was being overwritten each time.  I'm looking over the [WebClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but I'm not finding anything quite yet.  Is it possible to do something like this (keep in mind this is pseudo-code and I know it's not correct):

```
For each webclient in currentWebclients
    If webclientUrl = url Then CancelAsync()
Next
```

?

[edit 2]

Here's how I have the datagridview set up, as each download is added:

```
    Dim n As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
    DataGridView1.Rows.Item(n).Cells(0).Value = programName
```

Then I update the percent complete for each download:

```
    For Rowindex = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If DataGridView1.Rows(Rowindex).Cells(0).Value = programName Then
            DataGridView1.Rows.Item(Rowindex).Cells(1).Value = percent
            DataGridView1.Rows.Item(Rowindex).Cells(3).Value = "Cancel"
        End If
    Next
```

percent comes from DownloadProgressChanged:

```
Dim percent As String = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString
```

Cells(3) is the DataGridViewButtonColumn, ie the Cancel button for each download

Cells(2) is reserved for Error messages

In DownloadFileCompleted, I do handle

```
If e.Cancelled = True
```

Also, when a given download completes, I clear the row:

```
    For Rowindex = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If DataGridView1.Rows(Rowindex).Cells(0).Value = programName Then
            DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(Rowindex)
        End If
    Next
```

As is, everything is functional except for the cancel buttons.  Where I'm stuck is how to reference to a specific webclient in the CellContentClick sub above.

I did some testing in CellContentClick:

```
        Dim i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
        MessageBox.Show(DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value)
```

This does properly show the name of the download (located in the first cell) when I click on the buttons  in the DataGridViewButtonColumn - not 100% helpful, but it may be a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I've been kind of reading and trying to figure this one out since you posted it.

WebClient doesn't support multiple connections, which you actually caught when you found out you were overwriting it at the class level every time.

If I'm not mistaken, DataGridView has either an object or some other property that essentially allows you to hide the relevant data object right within its rows. You will need to do that for each download so that you can do something similar to what you've suggested above, with:

```
For each webclient in currentWebclients
    If webclientUrl = url Then CancelAsync()
Next
```

You can either create a chiild class for WebClient that will expose a nice human-reabable string to place into the row, or place the WebClient object right into the collection and call CancelAsync on the client as necessary

Edit: Here is some code illustrating what I meant above:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Foo bar = new Foo();
        Foo bar2 = new Foo();
        bar.fooInt = 12;
        bar2.fooInt = 13;

        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(bar, bar2);

        (dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value as Foo).fooInt = 3;
    }

    private class Foo
    {
        public Foo() { }
        public int fooInt = 0;
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Foo Int is: " + fooInt.ToString();
        }
    }
```

In this case, dataGridView1 is a form component I added to my form and manually created columns for. With a data grid view you can add an object to a cell and it will appear with the proper text so long as you override the `ToString()` method to show what you want. In your case, you will want a class to inherit from WebClient that just exposes "Cancel" in `ToString()`.

Run my above code to see how it works, but this is essentially what you want:

```
    private function someCreationFunction() 
    {
        WebClientChild wcc = new WebClientChild();
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(wcc, "");
    }

    private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[rowIndex].Value as WebClientChild).CancelAsync();

    }

    private class WebClientChild : WebClient
    {
        public WebClientChild() : base() { }
        public override string ToString() { return "Cancel"; }
    }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: [edit 2] in the original post shows how I have the DataGridView set up + some potentially helpful testing results - still working on it but this is a tough one...

Comment: I refactored my answer to more thoroughly explain what I meant.